# Can you do q-learning with a Tuple observation space?

Tags: openai-gym, q-learning

I build a custom Open AI Gym Environment that uses simple Tuple observation space.

```
self.observation_space = spaces.Tuple((spaces.Discrete(2,),spaces.Discrete(1)))
```

But when I try to use q-learning examples they use

```
observation_space.n
```

Is there a way to use q-learning with this kind of observation space?

Comment: Where are you using observation_space.n in your q-learning code?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the same issue in case anyone is still reading:
As Tuple spaces don´t have an attribute `n` I used a workaround by simply defining it myself:
`self.observation_space.n = self.dimension1 * self.dimension2`
basically multiplying the Discrete space input-parameters of the Tuple. Hope that makes sense